# Unable to understand error with unzip

Tags: unix, unzip

I have some *.zip files. I was trying to unzip these files through `unzip` command in Unix. But it is giving some trouble which I can not understand.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
unzip file.zip
```

It is giving the following error

```
bad CRC 64162f32  (should be b326db0b)
```

I have also tried some other way, which is

```
zcat file.zip > file.txt
```

and it is giving the following error

```
invalid compressed data--crc error
```

How should I solve this problem. Each `*.zip` file is almost 20GB in size.

Answer (score 2):

A `CRC` error means **[cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)**, basically, a checksum of all files contained within the .zip file - this message is showing you that the checksum known the the .zip file, *b326db0b*, *did not match* the checksum that it just calculated while trying to extract the files, *64162f32*.

This message is telling you that your *.zip* file is corrupt.

Were these files zipped locally? Or downloaded from a remote server? If transferred across the network, always do an `md5sum` on your files, and verify it against the server to verify you actually downloaded all the bytes you were supposed to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These are downloaded from a remote server. Now the best thing would be to check/download from the server again?

Comment: Do you have access to remote server? It would be wise to do an `md5sum` against the .zip file on the server, and the zip file that you have downloaded. If these checksums mismatch, you know there was an error on the wire, and you have a corrupt file. If the checksum matches, the zip files could have been corrupted on the server itself, either through HDD issues, or possibly even the zipping process.

Comment: `md5sum` on my zip file is giving an alphanumerical string. Should I compare this with the `md5sum` results on the server?